# What does the .net framework do during a blocking call?

Tags: .net

I'm observing some strange behavior in my code and I'm trying to track down the source.  I have two single threaded .net applications running and sending WCF messages to each other on the same machine.  They are very simple, there is a blocking write and then a blocking read.  I have noticed that on my blocking call in my log, 99.99% of the time I read / write in ~10 ms.  However in very rare circumstances, it may take 500-2000 ms.  I'm trying to understand exactly why this might be.  I have a few odd quirks to my app that I am tracking down and may be the culprit, but I was wondering if this was entering into territory where there's something about the framework that I don't understand.

So my question is this, when there's something like a blocking call, does a .net application start running a background process (such as garbage collection) while the main thread of execution is blocked?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's possible that garbage collection is the culprit. Any number of things could be causing the delay. For example, the operating system might be swapping one or both of your threads out of memory to do something else. Or a higher priority thread is preventing one or both of the threads from running. Hard to say. Can you post some code so we get a better idea of where you're experiencing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Garbage collector has its own dedicated resources so it does not matter if you are using a  blocking call or not.**

Blocking call basically means **running a long running task on the *UI thread***. Depending on the type of application (WPF, Windows, Console), definition of UI thread differs but while you are running a task on the UI thread, all messages for UI thread get queued up.

The effect you are seeing could be due to some other issues for example **Disk** or **Network** bottlenecks causing delay in the long running task. Using perfmon and matching the timing of your delays with the perfmon logs can be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the testing suggestion.  I'll give it a shot and see what I can drudge up.  I realize that performance is a complicated question, so I was trying to rule out .net performance sinks that I might not be aware of.  Thanks for resolving the question of the GC and the perfmon idea.

Comment: This looks like an oddity for example hard drive spindle waking up after sleeping or similar.

Answer (score 4):

You need to take into account the fact that there are many other applications running on your system. Usually things may run smoothly but every so often you may have several applications vie for processor time which will cause you to see delays. The weird lag that you see .01% of the time probably has little to do with .NET and more with what's going on in the OS at that particular point in time.

I don't think the issue is with the garbage collection. Your apps sound fairly simple and tight and whatever garbage there is to collect is probably minimal. You're running a development machine and if you're like most developers you'll have all sorts of servers, IDEs, text editors and dozens of web browser tabs open at the same time. Try this: Open heavier apps until your physical memory is over 75% utilization, or higher. (Even doing Alt+Tab between apps will seem/be slow.) I'm guessing that you will see greater delays and more often because there will be many more page faults and therefore many more hits to the hard drive (major bottleneck) slowing down the entire process.

Comment: Good idea, thanks, I'll give it a shot.  I realize that this is a complicated question with a ton of culprits, I was just trying to rule out possible .net ones that I didn't know about.  Thanks for the testing idea.

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is this, when there's
>   something like a blocking call, does a
>   .net application start running a
>   background process (such as garbage
>   collection) while the main thread of
>   execution is blocked?

What the CLR is doing during a blocking call is totally non-deterministic and not something you could rely upon. The discrepancies you are observing could be due to many factors you cannot control such as network latencies.

Answer (score 0):

First if your not using the [svctraceutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) make sure to use it as it will give you a load of info.  what WCF does depends on the hundreds of configuration options you set with your service/client.  Assuming your using some binding built on top of tcp during those long outlier calls it is reestablishing the session or retransmitting failed packets.  The good and bad of using a framework is you don't need to worry about the specifics as long as it meets your needs.  If you need fine grained control you could always implement a custom binding or use raw TCP/IP communication.